# Exceptions in ANSI C

Tags: c, exceptions, exception-handling

Would it be possible to implement exception mechanism in pure ANSI C similar to the one used in popular OOP languages (with familiar `try-catch-finally` clauses)?

If yes then how?

I'm especially interested how would anyone jump from function to the `catch` block bypassing all remaining code in `try` block?

Comment: [longjmp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setjmp.h)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible but has limitations. An implementation would utilize `setjmp()` / `longjmp()`. You can see an example implementation here: http://aceunit.sourceforge.net/doxygen/ExceptionHandling_8h.html
Beware: return within try-blocks would be a bug!

Comment: You mean return within `catch` blocks would be a bug, right?

Comment: actually, `return` is wrong anywhere between `try` and `endtry`. If you `return` between `try` and `endtry`, the global `currentExceptionBuffer` is not reset to its old value, and the `longjmp()` performed by a `throw` would end up in garbled stack.

Comment: So would a goto crossing the boundary of the `try{}endtry` block

Comment: That's a major limitation.  It means that you can't use a try/catch block in any function that returns a value.  Unless, perhaps, you store the result in a variable and return it outside the try.

Comment: Exactly, you first need a `goto` that jumps to after the `endtry` in order to `return`. Yes it has limitations. Lots of. I'd never say it's beautiful or good.

Comment: @ChristianHujer What about https://code.google.com/p/exceptions4c/ ? Have you tried that library? Does it have the same limitations?

Comment: @mrpyo [it does.](https://code.google.com/p/exceptions4c/wiki/drawbacks) Either way C doesn't provide any native assistance for any auto cleanup based on blocks (the windows compiler does have `try-catch-finally` built in but that is non-portable), any C++ to C compilers with exceptions will replace any program flow crossing in and out of the try block with the proper cleanup and setup code.